# How can I flatten double arrays in mongoDB?

Tags: ruby, arrays, mongodb

Some fields in my mongoDB documents look like this:

```
{
...
Countries: [["Spain", "France"]]
...
}
```

Or this:

```
{
...
Countries: [["Spain"],["Russia", "Egypt"]]
...
}
```

What I want to do is to turn `[["Spain", "France"]]` into `["Spain", "France"]` and `[["Spain"],["Russia", "Egypt"]]` into `["Spain", "Russia", "Egypt"]`, similar to using the `flatten` method in Ruby.

Is there a way to flatten arrays in mongoDB? I need to flatten arrays in all documents in entire collection, not just a single doc, if that matters, also, the values and their quantity in arrays varies between documents.

I am also using Ruby as a driver for mongo, so a method using a Ruby driver would be also useful to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data for Countries are not in a good format, so you may consider to convert them. This is a script to flatten the array in Countries field and save it the origin documents that you can run in a mongo shell:

```
function flattenArray(inArr) {
    var ret = [];
    inArr.forEach(function(arr) {
        if (arr.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") > -1) {
           ret = ret.concat(flattenArray(arr));
        } else {
           ret.push(arr);                   
        }
    });
    return ret;
}


db.collection.find({
  'Countries': {
    '$exists': true
  }
}).forEach(function(doc){
  doc.Countries = flattenArray(doc.Countries);
  db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 22):

In Mongo 3.4+ you can use `$reduce` to flatten 2d arrays.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: {
        "countries": {
          $reduce: {
            input: '$Countries',
            initialValue: [],
            in: {$concatArrays: ['$$value', '$$this']}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

Docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/

Comment: Boosting this answer, `$reduce` is a great choice. `$reduce` can flatten array of arrays (2D), or arrays of objects-with-arrays... (use `input: $outerArray.innerArrayPropertyName`). I can't tell if it's possible to flatten array-of-array-of-arrays (3D) with one projection..., I tried [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/je02tXAIwxl) but I think it requires nested `$reduce`, which don't work as I'd expect (maybe the ambiguity of `$$value` and `$$this`). Can do with multiple projections/steps, as shown [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iP4ztPICGhF);  might still be better than '$unwind`

Answer (score 8):

You need perform an aggregation operation with two [unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stages and a single [group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage. The basic rule being you unwind as many times as the level of nest depth. Here the level of nesting is 2, so we unwind two times.

```
 collection.aggregate([
 {$unwind => "$Countries"},
 {$unwind => "$Countries"},
 {$group => {"_id":"$_id","Countries":{$push => "$Countries"}}}
 ])
```

The first `$unwind` stage produces the result:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a32e0fc2eaf05fc77a5ea4"),
        "Countries" : [
                "Spain",
                "France"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a32e4ec2eaf05fc77a5ea5"),
        "Countries" : [
                "Spain"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a32e4ec2eaf05fc77a5ea5"),
        "Countries" : [
                "Russia",
                "Egypt"
        ]
}
```

The second `$unwind` stage further flattens the `Countries` array:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54a32e0fc2eaf05fc77a5ea4"), "Countries" : "Spain" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54a32e0fc2eaf05fc77a5ea4"), "Countries" : "France" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54a32e4ec2eaf05fc77a5ea5"), "Countries" : "Spain" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54a32e4ec2eaf05fc77a5ea5"), "Countries" : "Russia" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54a32e4ec2eaf05fc77a5ea5"), "Countries" : "Egypt" }
```

Now the final `$group` stage groups the records based on the `_id`,and accumulates the country names in a single array.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a32e4ec2eaf05fc77a5ea5"),
        "Countries" : [
                "Spain",
                "Russia",
                "Egypt"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54a32e0fc2eaf05fc77a5ea4"),
        "Countries" : [
                "Spain",
                "France"
        ]
}
```

If you wish to keep other fields in the document then you need to explicitly specify the names of the fields other than the country field,(field1,field2,etc..), using the `$first` operator. You can write/overwrite a collection by specifying the name of the collection in the `$out` stage.

```
collection.aggregate([
 {$unwind => "$Countries"},
 {$unwind => "$Countries"},
 {$group => {"_id":"$_id","Countries":{$push => "$Countries"},
             "field1":{$first => "$field1"}}},
 {$out => "collection"}
 ])
```

You need to explicitly specify the fields so that you don't get a redundant `Countries` field.

You can use the `$$ROOT` system variable to store the entire document, but that would make the `Countries` field redundant.One outside the `doc` and one inside the `doc`.

```
collection.aggregate([
 {$unwind => "$Countries"},
 {$unwind => "$Countries"},
 {$group => {"_id":"$_id","Countries":{$push => "$Countries"},
             "doc":{$first => "$$ROOT"}}},
 {$out => "collection"}
 ])
```

Comment: I wrote the result 3 seconds sooner than you ;), it was just interesting. anyway +1

Comment: @Disposer Yeah - you beat me to it. Took time to format the results :), +1 for your aggregation. :)

Comment: Thanks. Can I clarify two more questions then. I have noticed that this group operator returns only specified fields (id and countries). Is it possible to include all other fields without manually specifying each of them. Because there are many other fields, and the db is not optimized yet, there are even unique fields shared only by a very small portion of docs and it would be bloody hard to search and specify all of them.
And second, maybe stupid question: how do I overwrite original collection with aggregate output?

Comment: @AntonDinoMois, You should explicitly specify all the other fields. You can make a list of fields and come up with a unified structure, separate the mandatory and optional fields and make entries. That would be my suggestion. You need to use the $out stage of the pipeline to overwrite the collection. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
db.test2.aggregate([
   {"$unwind" : "$Countries"},
   {"$unwind" : "$Countries"},
   {$group : { _id : '$_id', Countries: { $addToSet: "$Countries" }}},
]).result
```

Answer (score 0):

since the version 5 of }, we have an alternative using the $function operator like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $addFields: { 
        Countries: {
          $function: {
            body: function(items) {
              return [].concat(...items)
            },
            args: [ "$Countries" ],
            lang: "js"
          }
       }
     }
   }
])
```

the ideal solution would be to be able to use $concatArrays but unfortunately this operator is not able to take into account an array field (at the time of this writing). There's a ticket in the mongodb backlog about this limitation on array fields : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31991 . If you are interested by the flexibility brought by this enhancement please vote. This ticket has been here since 2019 so it seems to need help to be prioritized ;-)