# MongoDB flatten arbitrary nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document structure with arbitrarily nested arrays similar to follows, which I want to flatten during an aggregation pipeline:

```json
{ 
  "data": [
    "one",
    [
      "two", 
      "three"
    ],
    [
      [ "four" ],
      [ "five" ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

Expected result:

```json
{ "data": [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ] }
```

Existing question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735382/how-can-i-flatten-double-arrays-in-mongodb/57650549) gives some ideas (especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57650549/388827) answer), however not totally generically with an **arbitrary depth** of nesting.

Is there some more generic solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Joe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67288331/8987128), No straight way to handle this kind of operation in MongoDB, You should think about your schema design as per your query requirement.

If you think you really needed this, you can try MongoDB Defines a custom aggregation function or expression in JavaScript, ​[$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) and [$accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/),

```
{
  $project: {
​    data: {
      ​$function: {
        ​body: function(data) {
          ​const flatten = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(Array.isArray(b) ? flatten(b) : b), []);
          ​return flatten(data);
        ​},
        ​args: ["$data"],
        ​lang: "js"
      ​}
    ​}
  ​}
​}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K0_qkxuFQF2)

> **IMPORTANT**
>
> Executing JavaScript inside an aggregation expression may decrease performance. Only use the `$function` operator if the provided pipeline operators cannot fulfill your application's needs.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB doesn't provide any looping or recursion, so doing anything arbitrarily many times is simply not possible.

You could programmatically build an aggregation pipeline in the client that could flatten an array dozens of levels deep, but the overall pipeline must fit within an 16MB request document, so it won't support arbitrary depth.