# convert nested array of strings to linear array of strings in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to convert nested array of strings to one single array, in version 3.6, using `$reduce`. Please consider the following data structure & query:

**data structure**:

```
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "settings" : {
        "button" : {
            "elem" : [ 
                {
                    "design_id" : "bk_btn_V2",
                    "link_to" : "page",
                    "link_url" : "/booknow",
                    "status" : true,
                    "mobile_status" : true,
                    "style" : {},
                    "title" : "BOOK SERVICE"
                }, 
                {
                    "design_id" : "bk_btn_V2",
                    "link_to" : "page",
                    "link_url" : "/contact-us",
                    "status" : true,
                    "mobile_status" : true,
                    "style" : {},
                    "title" : "CONTACT US"
                }
            ],
            "mobile_status" : true,
            "status" : true
        },
        "list" : {
            "status" : true,
            "mobile_status" : true,
            "items" : [ 
                {
                    "status" : true,
                    "mobile_status" : true,
                    "title" : {
                        "status" : true,
                        "mobile_status" : true,
                        "content" : "Book Appointment",
                        "style" : {}
                    },
                    "desc" : {
                        "status" : true,
                        "mobile_status" : true,
                        "content" : "Use our convenient booking form to make an appointment.",
                        "style" : {}
                    },
                    "media" : {
                        "status" : true,
                        "mobile_status" : true,
                        "type" : "image",
                        "urls" : [ 
                            "/assets/images/book-appointment.jpg"
                        ],
                        "style" : {
                            "opacity" : 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "status" : true,
                    "mobile_status" : true,
                    "title" : {
                        "status" : true,
                        "mobile_status" : true,
                        "content" : "Get Confirmation",
                        "style" : {}
                    },
                    "desc" : {
                        "status" : true,
                        "mobile_status" : true,
                        "content" : "You will receive a confirmation from us within 30 seconds.",
                        "style" : {}
                    },
                    "media" : {
                        "status" : true,
                        "mobile_status" : true,
                        "type" : "image",
                        "urls" : [ 
                            "/assets/images/get-confirmation.jpg"
                        ],
                        "style" : {
                            "opacity" : 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "status" : true,
                    "mobile_status" : true,
                    "title" : {
                        "status" : true,
                        "mobile_status" : true,
                        "content" : "Relax, Its Done!",
                        "style" : {}
                    },
                    "desc" : {
                        "status" : true,
                        "mobile_status" : true,
                        "content" : "We can't wait to service you! See you soon.",
                        "style" : {}
                    },
                    "media" : {
                        "status" : true,
                        "mobile_status" : true,
                        "type" : "image",
                        "urls" : [ 
                            "/assets/images/relax-its-done.jpg"
                        ],
                        "style" : {
                            "opacity" : 1.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "style" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

**query**:

```
db.getCollection('draft_sections').aggregate([
{"$match": {
    "$and": [
        {"$or": [
            {"settings.button.elem": {"$elemMatch": {"title": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}},
            {"settings.short_form_btn.elem": {"$elemMatch": {"title": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}},
            {"settings.list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"title.content": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}},
            {"settings.list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"sub_title.content": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}},
            {"settings.list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"desc.content": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}},
            {"settings.list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"button.elem": {"$elemMatch": {"title": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}}}},
            {"settings.list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"title.content": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}}}},
            {"settings.list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"sub_title.content": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}}}},
            {"settings.list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"desc.content": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}}}},
            {"settings.list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"button.elem": {"$elemMatch": {"title": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}}}}}},
            {"settings.description.settings.button.elem": {"$elemMatch": {"title": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}},
            {"settings.social_list.settings.list.items": {"$elemMatch": {"title": {"$exists": true, "$ne": ""}}}},
        ]},
        {"language_code": "en"},
    ],
}},
{"$project": {
    "arr_strings": [
        "$settings.button.elem.title",
        "$settings.list.items.title.content",
        "$settings.list.items.sub_title.content",
        "$settings.list.items.desc.content",
        "$settings.list.items.button.elem.title",
        "$settings.list.items.list.items.title.content",
        "$settings.list.items.list.items.sub_title.content",
        "$settings.list.items.list.items.desc.content",
        "$settings.list.items.list.items.button.elem.title",
        "$settings.description.settings.button.elem.title",
        "$settings.social_list.settings.list.items.title",
    ],
}},
{"$unwind": "$arr_strings"},
{"$group": {
    "_id":             "null",
    "all_arr_strings": {"$addToSet": "$arr_strings"},
}},
{"$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "strings": {"$setUnion": [
        {"$reduce": {
            "input": "$all_arr_strings",
            "initialValue": [],
            "in":           {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]},
        }},
    ]},
}},
])
```

I have given here the query with maximum fields I am going to use. Now Some fields are returned as null. As per MongoDB documentation, $reduce will return null if any one inout element is null. So I am getting the whole result as null. Is there a different way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `filter` operator to remove `null` values in array.

Like this:

```
{
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "string": {
        "$setUnion": [
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$all_arr_strings",
                  "as": "arr",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                      {
                        "$type": "$$arr"
                      },
                      "array",
                      
                    ],
                    
                  }
                }
              },
              // "as": "primaryArr",
              "initialValue": [],
              "in": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$$this",
                      "as": "arrElem",
                      "cond": {
                        "$eq": [
                          {
                            "$type": "$$arrElem"
                          },
                          "string"
                        ],
                        
                      }
                    },
                    
                  },
                  "$$value"
                ]
              },
              
            }
          },
          
        ],
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
```

Therefore your entire Aggregation query will look something like this:

```
db.getCollection('draft_sections').aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "arr_strings": [
        "$settings.button.elem.title",
        "$settings.list.items.title.content",
        "$settings.list.items.sub_title.content",
        "$settings.list.items.desc.content",
        "$settings.list.items.button.elem.title",
        "$settings.list.items.list.items.title.content",
        "$settings.list.items.list.items.sub_title.content",
        "$settings.list.items.list.items.desc.content",
        "$settings.list.items.list.items.button.elem.title",
        "$settings.description.settings.button.elem.title",
        "$settings.social_list.settings.list.items.title",
      ],
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$arr_strings"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "null",
      "all_arr_strings": {
        "$addToSet": "$arr_strings"
      },
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "string": {
        "$setUnion": [
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$all_arr_strings",
                  "as": "arr",
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [
                      {
                        "$type": "$$arr"
                      },
                      "array",
                      
                    ],
                    
                  }
                }
              },
              // "as": "primaryArr",
              "initialValue": [],
              "in": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$$this",
                      "as": "arrElem",
                      "cond": {
                        "$eq": [
                          {
                            "$type": "$$arrElem"
                          },
                          "string"
                        ],
                        
                      }
                    },
                    
                  },
                  "$$value"
                ]
              },
              
            }
          },
          
        ],
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tR9kG1V8TYR)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Null values are removed using $filter but I have multi layered nested arrays. So I have some elements which are returned as arrays. Is there a correct to get only linear array of strings ?

Comment: @Amandeepkaur sorry for my delayed response, I have updated the answer, check is this is what you are looking for

Comment: Its not working as expected. It removed the array that was coming in the output before.

before:
{
    "strings": [
        "BOOK SERVICE",
        "Book Appointment",
        "CONTACT US",
        [ 
            "VIEW"
        ]
    ]
}

after:
{
    "strings": [
        "BOOK SERVICE",
        "Book Appointment",
        "CONTACT US"
    ]
}

Comment: @ hhharsha36 Can you help me for the above comment? It is not yet solved.

Comment: @Amandeepkaur can you provide the exact input data for the scenario you are facing and expected output? Provide the data from the group stage since there are no issues in previous pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

I found the quick & short answer to my problem after doing a lot of research. It was quite simple:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27735555/7533957