# Aggregation on an array of objects - Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a tracker for BMI, weight etc. with Express and Mongoose and I want to make a function to return some metrics like lowest amount, average, maximum but in my model for the tracker I also have an array of objects like calories intake that contains food name, quantity and calories and calories burned like activity, time, calories. As an example an element from the array

```
{
  "trackers": [
    {
      "_id": "657b58f0e05669de911e9c4a",
      "userId": "654d08d00149cc5b1ac434e7",
      "date": "2023-12-20",
      "caloriesIntake": [
        {
          "foodName": "pizza",
          "quantity": "300",
          "calories": 788.7
        },
        {
          "foodName": "test",
          "quantity": "20",
          "calories": 100
        },
        {
          "foodName": "cheese",
          "quantity": "20",
          "calories": 78.78
        }
      ],
      "caloriesBurned": [
        {
          "activity": "Basketball, shooting baskets",
          "time": "50",
          "calories": 272.5
        },
        {
          "activity": "test",
          "time": "20",
          "calories": 200
        }
      ],
      "__v": 5,
      "neck": 20,
      "weight": 70
    },
    {
      "_id": "657b59e7e05669de911e9c5e",
      "userId": "654d08d00149cc5b1ac434e7",
      "date": "2023-12-28",
      "caloriesIntake": [
        {
          "foodName": "ratatouille",
          "quantity": "400",
          "calories": 233.2
        },
        {
          "foodName": "test",
          "quantity": "30",
          "calories": 100
        }
      ],
      "caloriesBurned": [
        {
          "activity": "Swimming butterfly",
          "time": "30",
          "calories": 399.5
        },
        {
          "activity": "test",
          "time": "20",
          "calories": 400
        }
      ],
      "__v": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to make the sum of calories and then aggregation on it with $avg, $max, $min.

```
const result = await Tracker.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    userId: userId,
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                  _id: null,
                  avgBMI: { $avg: '$BMI' },
                  minBMI: { $min: '$BMI' },
                  maxBMI: { $max: '$BMI' },
                  avgCaloriesIntake: { $avg: { $sum: '$caloriesIntake.calories' }},
                  minCaloriesIntake: { $min: { $sum: '$caloriesIntake.calories' }},
                  maxCaloriesIntake: { $max: { $sum: '$caloriesIntake.calories' }},
                  minCaloriesBurned: { $min: { $sum: '$caloriesBurned.calories' }},
                  avgCaloriesBurned: { $avg: { $sum: '$caloriesBurned.calories' }},
                  maxCaloriesBurned: { $max: { $sum: '$caloriesBurned.calories' }},
                },
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  _id: 0,
                  avgBMI: 1,
                  minBMI: 1,
                  maxBMI: 1,
                  avgCaloriesIntake: 1,
                  minCaloriesIntake: 1,
                  maxCaloriesIntake: 1,
                  avgCaloriesBurned: 1,
                  minCaloriesBurned: 1,
                  maxCaloriesBurned: 1,
                },
              },
            ]).exec();
```

This is how I did it, I get the correct values for BMI and other that are not in an array but for the array I get the value 0. I also tried to have the $sum in the $group and do the aggregation in the $project but still the same result.

Do I take the values from the `calories` wrong? I tried $unwind on each array but then I get wrong values for every other field and still 0 for arrays.

This is also the result from the call:

```
{
  "metrics": {
    "avgBMI": null,
    "minBMI": null,
    "maxBMI": null,
    "avgCaloriesIntake": 0,
    "minCaloriesIntake": 0,
    "maxCaloriesIntake": 0,
    "minCaloriesBurned": 0,
    "avgCaloriesBurned": 0,
    "maxCaloriesBurned": 0
  }
}
```

The problem is that I get 0 when should be the average, minimum and maximum from the sums of each day.

Edit: The problem came from how the documents stored the `calories` value, initially they were Strings and I changed to Number but I did not delete old documents.
From:

```
{
   "activity": "test",
   "time": "20",
   "calories": "400"
}
```

to:

```
{
   "activity": "test",
   "time": 20,
   "calories": 400
}
```

Comment: It is more helpful for you to show a full sample json documents instead of just the array elements. Also please show the current output and explain what is incorrect

Comment: Based on your query, is this what each entry looks like? `{ userId: 1, caloriesBurned: [ { activity: "Ballroom dancing, fast", time: "50", calories: "332.50" }, { activity: "slow dancing", time: "10", calories: "10.50" } ], caloriesIntake: [ { activity: "eating food, fast", calories: "1234.5" }, { activity: "eating desert", calories: "4321.5" } ] }`? Provide some example data for at least one user with the expected results of your aggregation. Your query has `BMI` in it so there are obviously multiple values. Is it one record per user or multiple records?

Comment: And are your numbers _actually_ stored as **strings** instead of **numbers/floats**? That could be why you get all 0's.

Comment: The document just contains a date stored as string `date: String` and the other metrics are all number `BMI: Number` cause the user tracks one day's metrics as a document. The problem was indeed as @aneroid said with `calories` type. Originally it was saved as strings and I changed that but there were left old documents with String values for the calories key so that's why I kept getting 0s as result. After deleting the old documents and testing again in Thunder Client I get the correct results.

Comment: Ok, so do you want these stats _per user_ or do you want min/max/avg across all users? From your query with `$match: { userId: userId }` it looks like you want it for a specific user. And I see that userId `654d08d00149cc5b1ac434e7` is repeated - is that a  typo or can each user have multiple records? And you want to run aggregates across all records for a specific user?

Comment: Is your problem resolved now? I just saw your edits of changing fields from strings to numbers. It looks working fine in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pijdn2cyPFn).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, with the actual data fully provided, here's what you can do:

- Match on the userID value and `$group` with `_id: null` (which you've done)
- But in the `$group` stage, `$push` the values of the Intake and Burned arrays; which will make it *an array of arrays*.
- Then flatten those using `$reduce` ie [combine an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57650549/1431750) into one array.

  - You can overwrite the existing key to store the result but I've used a new key `combinedAllCaloriesIntake` so that yo can see the effect of the change when running each stage in playground.
- To mix things up a bit, since you have some values stored and strings instead numbers/doubles, I've changed some `calories` to strings. <sub>(The "272.5" in `caloriesBurned` in the first recond and the "233.2" in `caloriesIntake` in the seocnd record.)</sub>

  - To fix that - since you had data like that before - I've added a step to map this which will map all values to doubles.
  - Again, this could be done after the reduce stage but I decided to put them together.
- Now you have an array of doubles for Intake, and an array of doubles for Burned. So all that's need is the `$min`, `$max`, `$avg` for each.

```js
db.trackers.aggregate([
  // put the userId var here instead this
  { $match: { userId: "654d08d00149cc5b1ac434e7" } }, 
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      allCaloriesIntake: { $push: "$caloriesIntake.calories" },
      allCaloriesBurned: { $push: "$caloriesBurned.calories" }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      combinedAllCaloriesIntake: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $reduce: {
              // "flatten" an array of arrays
              input: "$allCaloriesIntake",
              initialValue: [],
              in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ]
              }
            }
          },
          as: "cals",
          // map each value to a double
          in: { $toDouble: "$$cals" }
        }
      },
      combinedAllCaloriesBurned: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $reduce: {
              // "flatten" an array of arrays
              input: "$allCaloriesBurned",
              initialValue: [],
              in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ]
              }
            }
          },
          as: "cals",
          // map each value to a double
          in: { $toDouble: "$$cals" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      // min, max, avg
      _id: 0,
      avgCaloriesIntake: { $avg: "$combinedAllCaloriesIntake" },
      minCaloriesIntake: { $min: "$combinedAllCaloriesIntake" },
      maxCaloriesIntake: { $max: "$combinedAllCaloriesIntake" },
      minCaloriesBurned: { $min: "$combinedAllCaloriesBurned" },
      avgCaloriesBurned: { $avg: "$combinedAllCaloriesBurned" },
      maxCaloriesBurned: { $max: "$combinedAllCaloriesBurned" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wZizcg0v1Fq)

Result:

```js
[
  {
    "avgCaloriesBurned": 318,
    "avgCaloriesIntake": 260.136,
    "maxCaloriesBurned": 400,
    "maxCaloriesIntake": 788.7,
    "minCaloriesBurned": 200,
    "minCaloriesIntake": 78.78
  }
]
```

---

Btw, wrt the issue you mentioned

> I tried $unwind on each array but then I get wrong values for every other field and still 0 for arrays.

In a single record, if the Intake array has 3 values and the Burned array has 2 values, since you can `$unwind` only one at a time, you'll end up with 6 records, with repetitions so that will break the math for *`$avg`* (min & max would stay the same). Also, you would have got `0` as the result since they were probably strings. The `$min` & `$max` *appear to work* because it's applying "string" logic. But it's not actually correct.

Sample input:

```js
[
  { "key": "1" },  // this is a string
  { "key": 2 }  // this is a number
]
```

Using min/max without converting them gives *obviously wrong* results:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "min": { "$min": "$key" },
      "max": { "$max": "$key" }
    }
  }
])
```

Invalid min-max result due to mixed string/numeric comparison:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "max": "1",
    "min": 2
  }
]
```